# Como Puedo Compartir UN Archivo de .Py a .Exe por medio virtual y otras preguntas mas de pytho y pynstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

miren tengos dos preguntas con respecto a python y pyintaller , yo creo un archivo de .py a .exe , lo quiero compartir con alguien mas , ese archivo se ejecuta en ese ordenador sin necesidad de tener python instalado? , y ademas se puede compartir por correo electronico el .exe ? , intente hacerlo , pero me sale q el archivo tiene virus, eso me sale en gmail , enteonces quisiera saber como se le puede eliminar el virus al archivo .exe? y otra cosa como lo puedo compartir por medio virtual ?

y disculpen el titulo no se como colocarle uno adecuado.

les agradeceria su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respondiendo a la primer pregunta, pyintaller transforma tu .py a un .exe. permitiendo que se pueda correr sin necesidad de tener el framework de python instalado. En pocas palabras, te genera un ejecutable "stand-alone" que podras compartirlo para que la otra persona pueda ejecutarlo.

aquí puedes obtener mas información: https://www.pyinstaller.org/

con respecto a enviar el .exe por mail te va a resultar imposible, ya que la gran mayoría de los correos electrónicos no permiten el envió de archivos ejecutables por un tema de seguridad. Esto no significa que el archivo este infectado.
Puedes compartir tus archivos utilizando otro medio como carpeta compartida en google drive o one drive.

si no sabes como hacerlo, te recomiendo [esta guia](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es).

Comment: OK.muchas gracias estoy experimentando con los programas en otros pc , necesitaba eso. muchas gracias buen dia.